# Как на php определить ширину, высоту и тип фото?

Tags: php

Как вывести параметры для фотографий на php ?

```
$foto = "025.jpg"; 
<img src = "<?php echo $foto ; ?>" />
```

Хочу вывести например: ширина: 400 высота: 600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про функцию `getimagesize()` на `php`.

```
$foto = "image015.jpg"; 
    // получаем массив, содержащий размеры изображения 
    $size = getimagesize ("$foto"); 

    $flag = array(
        1=>'GIF', 
        2=>'JPG', 
        3=>'PNG', 
        4=>'SWF', 
        5=>'PSD', 
        6=>'BMP', 
        7=>'TIFF(байтовый порядок intel)', 
        8=>'TIFF(байтовый порядок motorola)', 
        9=>'JPC', 
        10=>'JP2', 
        11=>'JPX'
    );
```

Вывод:

```
echo "Ширина: " . $size[0] .'<br>'; 
echo "Высота: " . $size[1] .'<br>'; 
echo "Тип изображения: " . $flag[$size[2]] .'<br>'; 
//echo "Ширина и Высота: " . $size[3] .'<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите доки на php.net, функция getimagesize
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?